# Ubuntu way to run sysctl -p on each boot?

Tags: boot, init, init.d

I made some changes to sysctl.conf but now need to run sysctl -p on each boot. I can always create an init script to have it run automatically on boot, but I was wondering if there was an Ubuntu / Debian way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu the Upstart job `procps` (`/etc/init/procps.conf`) already does that for you.

Comment: Hi Florian, I understand that your post has the intention to be educational. But an unwary user could imagine that he/she have to edit procps.conf what would be a disaster, don't you agree?

Comment: it turns out there is more than just `sysctl.conf` and `procps.conf`: [the issue with pm-utils and laptop-mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443032/etc-sysctl-conf-doesnt-persist-after-reboot)

Answer (score 3):

There is a better and more ellegant way:

create your configuration file on /etc/sysctl.d/ directory.

For example, if you changing kernel parameters due to database requirements, create a file:

```
/etc/sysctl.d/60-mysql.conf
```

and add your own parameters inside it. To execute it:

```
service procps restart
```

Just to note:

- procps is a system file and it should **NEVER** be edited.
- /etc/sysctl.conf should not be edited either because it can be changed on a system/kernel upgrade and if it's differente from expected, upgrade will be halted asking if newer version can replace current one.

Reference:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sysctl.8.html

Answer (score 2):

You add your desired sysctls into `/etc/sysctl.conf` and they will be applied at boot time. However, if you have updated `/etc/sysctl.conf` and what to apply it immediately, run:

```
sudo sysctl --system
```

Comment: It's actually `sysctl -p` to reload `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. You can also read the settings from your own file, by specifying it after the `-p` option, for example `sysctl -p /home/user/custom.conf`.